# Install4j - Mac OSX Single Bundle with Java 7 - app launch error

Tags: macos, java-7, install4j

Install4j v5.1.6: Creating Media File type "Mac OSX Single Bundle" bundled with Java 1.7 JRE (Java 1.7u45) causes the following error displayed when the Install File is launched: 
"You need at least a 1.7 Java Virtual Machine to install [my app name].  Please download it from http://www.apple.com"
Works fine if I bundle without JRE by selecting in the Media Wizard JRE step: "Installed OpenJDK JRE (Java 7 and higher)", but I need app bundled with a JRE.  Install File launched on OSX version 10.7.5.  Created Install File with Install4j running on Win 7 64bit.

Comment: You will need to elaborate in order to get answer, or avoid having your question removed for being low-quality.  Welcome to the site, though.  Keep at it

Comment: There's some interesting information at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html that talks about packaging Java apps for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

can u elaborate on how did you add jre and from where u download those bundles? Usually you need to download jre from install4j IDE and can bundle the same with your application.